# How to prevent the overload/overuse on a (web) API endpoint?

Tags: endpoint, webapi

Let's say I have a web server up and running with an API endpoint (for example `.../post`) which allows a user to create something (and save into the database). Someone could use a loop to send a huge amount of requests to that endpoint and the database will end up have rubbish data.

What is considered the best practice to protect an endpoint from being overused/overloaded by someone (hacker) in order to prevent a database overflow?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend user or IP filtering. Basically, keep a track of every request and if someone exceeds a certain number, do not allow further requests.

You can implement it by your own by keeping a track of the number of requests of every user or IP, or you can use some already build code like [Rack attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to distribute API keys such that each API user has their own key to be used like a password, and when you discover one is being abused you could revoke their previous data entries to the system. If you do even a cursory google search for API security, you get [lots of useful links (like this one)](https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way/).